# Center-align entire worksheet

Tags: excel, powershell, text-alignment

My current code only aligns the first 5 lines of Excel worksheet:

```psh
$xlCenter=-4108 
$excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $True
$excel.Rows.Item("1:5").HorizontalAlignment = $xlCenter
```

But there is no telling how many rows my program will read from a database. How to center align all the rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't restrict the rows you apply the format to:

```psh
$excel.Rows.HorizontalAlignment = $xlCenter
```